why track $index works fine for dynamic array?
I'm experimenting with this code since I saw many people using track $index
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    @for (item of array; track $index) {
<!-- behave exactly as -->
<!-- @for (item of array; track item.value) { -->
      <li>{{$index}}: {{item.value}}</li>
    }
  </ul>

  <button (click)="removeSecond()">remove second</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  array = [{ value: 'A' }, { value: 'B' }, { value: 'C' }, { value: 'D' }];

  removeSecond() {
    this.array.splice(1, 1);
  }
}

I expected that if the array changed by splice for example, it will show incorrect items but it doesn't and keep showing the proper ones, I thought it'd show A, B, C not A, C, D
now I don't really understand how track work

try comparing which dom html elements stay in the dom to understand how track works. angular change detection is still applied to the content in all of the currently existing elements and update the content if it was changed
